# Adjective for a decision that had no real alternative

Tags: word-choice

I'd like to express the fact that there were no viable alternatives to a decision I took.

> My decision to attend university X was *stringent / without alternative
>   / a no-brainer / objectively necessary* because it was the only one
>   offering the course in which I am interested.

I'm not sure whether *stringent* in this context is appropriate. The rest of the listed phrases in italics are passable for my taste but I'd like to use a **single word** to express the notion of having no real alternative.

Comment: Perhaps, "forced"?

Comment: @deadrat: Thanks! "forced" is alright but sounds a bit too, well, violent and negative.

Comment: I like "forced" and don't think it suggests violence in this context. Hobson's choice describes the situation very clearly though isn't the wording you want (I'd suggest you rephrase); if you want to avoid "forced" then **my hands were tied in this decision** is also a useful phrase.

Comment: True, "forced" doesn't really suggest violence. But I think it evokes a sense of helplessness, which is not what I'm trying to say. I prefer the tone of the phrase that Edwin Ashworth has suggested: [_my decision was made for me_](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/259071/adjective-for-a-decision-that-had-no-real-alternative/259077?noredirect=1#comments-259077)

Comment: You might also like "a foregone conclusion".

Comment: When I hear a choice was "forced", I personally don't think violence, I just think math. Specifically, game theory. So probably avoid using that in contexts where your readers don't know any game theory. ;)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You may use ***[inevitable](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/inevitable):***

> - Impossible to avoid or prevent; certain to happen.

(AHD)

Answer (score 22):

Your choice was a [foregone conclusion](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/foregone+conclusion), also sometimes expressed as fore-drawn conclusion.

Comment: Dunno why this guy got downvoted.  I think it's a perfect answer.

Comment: @loneboat: I didn't downvote, but I dislike this phrase because its literal meaning is unclear and unrelated to present usage. (It comes to us from *Othello* but even there it's a little murky.) Something that "is forgone" can be something preceded by something else, or that has gone (or in the classic style "is gone") before something else. So it seems to me the phrase can refer to either 1) an inevitable future event preceded by clear signs, or 2) a decision made too soon, before the gathering of evidence or careful deduction. When I hear it I suspect the speaker just isn't thinking.

Comment: @Beta: When I hear it, it's usually perfectly clear from the context which definition is meant.

Comment: Whilst a good solution, in common usage, this isn't a single word adjective, which is what the OP asked for.

Answer (score 12):

adj., **[ineluctable](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ineluctable)**

- impossible to avoid or evade
- My decision to attend university X was ineluctable..

> A five syllable beauty like ineluctable is obviously not the kind of
>   word you throw around in daily speech. It's far more often used as a
>   written word, as in the common phrase "ineluctable conclusion." ([vocab.com](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/ineluctable))

It is a **[Hobson's choice](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Hobson's+choice)** (in comments..)

> Hobson had an extensive stable of some 40 horses. This gave the
>   appearance to his customers that, upon entry, that customer would have
>   his or her choice of mounts, when in fact there was **only one**:

- Where to elect there is but one, / 'Tis Hobson's choice—take that, or none.

(wiki)

Comment: I prefer this over `inevitable` mostly because inevitability implies something happening because of fate or destiny, whereas `ineluctable` speaks more to the question's emphasis on a conclusion due to lack of alternatives. I would also consider `unavoidable`, but this is much better.

Answer (score 11):

**Obligatory** is the synonym I'd choose here.

> *obligatory*    adjective
>
> 1 forcing one's compliance or participation by or as if by law ...
>
> *Synonyms* compulsory, forced, imperative, incumbent, involuntary, necessary, nonelective, obligatory, peremptory, required

[[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/obligatory)]

Comment: Thanks a lot! _"My decision was obligatory, because ..."_ would you write that? Just asking, because I never saw _obligatory_ modifying _decision_ before.

Comment: I'd prefer 'My decision was made for me', or your 'There were no viable alternatives ...', if I'm not constrained by your 'My decision to attend university X was___'. We never know here whether a person has thought up an example frame to get suggestions for a preferred synonym, or whether they want the most natural-sounding rewrite. There aren't too many internet examples of  'obligatory decision'; [one is](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/mac/users/rauch/nvp/consistent/naomi_wolf.html)  'Wolf at least ...[says] that such a choice is in some circumstances the right, even obligatory, decision. '

Comment: I don't think it's idiomatic to describe a _decision_ as obligatory, but an _action_ or a _choice_ can be: 'My choice of university X was obligatory'.

Comment: Things are either idiomatic or not. I'd agree that the rephrasing is and the coupling with decision is not a collocation – but neither is it wrong. But as I say, I'd rephrase here if given a free choice.

Answer (score 9):

**Hobson's Choice**

A Hobson's choice is a free choice in which only one option is offered.

[Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hobson%27s_choice)

Comment: This is the first thing that popped into my mind, but it isn't a single word adjective, which is what the OP asked for.

Answer (score 5):

You made the [*obvious*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/obvious) choice. Given the options, one in particular was *obviously* and by far preferable to all others, so you chose that one.

Comment: This is the most *obvious* answer.

Answer (score 3):

[Compulsory](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/compulsory) would be appropriate:

> - If something is compulsory, you must do it because of a rule or law.

(Cambridge Dictionary)

Comment: I like this one, being derived from *compelled* and *compulsion*, which suggest complete lack of control over the decision. Rules or laws are generally the reason for a compulsory action, but not necessarily - you might want to make that clear.

Comment: It's not appropriate to the question though, because the decision was not made because of a rule but because of circumstances (no other choices available).

Answer (score 0):

I would say your decision was **natural** (M-W: having an essential relation with someone or something :  following from the nature of the one in question ).

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with "inescapable".

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inescapable)  sez: "incapable of being avoided, ignored, or denied."

Answer (score 0):

My decision to attend University X was constrained by the fact it was the only one offering ...

Constrained means the options were limited by an external factor or filter.

Answer (score -1):

How about one of these:
hinged
necessitated
apparent

My decision to attend university X /hinged on the fact that/ it was the only one offering the course in which I am interested.

My decision to attend university X was /necessitated as/ it was the only one offering the course in which I am interested.

My decision to attend university X was /apparent as/ it was the only one offering the course in which I am interested.

Answer (score -1):

Your decision was **[a formality](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/formality)**, as in *something done or happening as a matter of course and without question*. A mathematician might describe it as [**trivial**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/trivial), meaning simple, although non-mathematicians that carries an implication of being unimportant (which your choice of university certainly isn't).

Answer (score -1):

You made a **choiceless** decision.

Comment: I agree with this answer, but the phrase you present it in is an oxymoron (if there is no choice, then you're not making a decision). Perhaps it should be rephrased, e.g. "Your situation is choiceless."? Or is this an idiom I'm just not aware of?

Comment: @talrnu I agree it's not an ideal way of saying it; however, the question asks for a way to describe a decision that had no alternative. A decision made when there was no alternative is not much of a decision. In the OP's specific case, it was to go to the one school offering the course or to not take the course at all. That's still a decision, but when not taking the course isn't an option, one has no choices. Deciding to go to the school was a decision in which there was no real choice. A choiceless decision. My phrasing is as much oxymoronic as the question, which is rather fitting....

Comment: TL;DR, it's more of a poetic way of separating a choice (as being able to pick between feasible/desirable options) and a decision (as a more general/literal choosing between all options no matter how ridiculous or undesirable)

Comment: True, and on review it seems other answers are also oxymoronic. I guess this one just stood out so starkly due to the absoluteness of *choiceless*. It does have a nice fatalist/defeatist ring to it.